# Print/output utf-8 character from utf-8 code

Tags: javascript, ruby, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I have string containing utf8 code in my HTML file such as `/tr'&amp;#652;mp&amp;#618;t/`, I want the utf8 code to be printed as **utf8 character** in the document. `ˈtrəmpit`

Which library provide this functions? `Ruby`, `JavaScript` all works for me, `Python` is also okey.

Provided the document is already encoded in utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python, use e.g. (following [this post](http://fredericiana.com/2010/10/08/decoding-html-entities-to-text-in-python/)):

```
import HTMLParser
h=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print h.unescape('tr&#652;mp&#618;t')
# trʌmpɪt
```